# Работа с файлами сайта через sublime text

Tags: linux, sublime-text

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку, кто и как работает с файлами сайта. У сайта стоит владелец фалов и папок apache, стандартные доступы 755 на дирректории и 644 на файлы. root доступ закрыт.
Я монтирую дирректорию сайта по ssh от пользователя, который входит в группу apache и пытаюсь открывать файлы через sublime text, но так какдоступ только для чтения, то соответсвенно они не сохраняются.
Возможно работать через консоль, через vim например запустив его через sudo, но хотелось бы именно редактировать файлы напрямую через sublime text.

Comment: Я бы предложил владельца сменить на файлах. apache в большинство файлов сайта писать не надо, а только читать. Только на каталоги куда при работе сайта возможна запись скриптами надо ставить права для пользователя под которым работают скрипты, т.е. apache

Comment: «пользователя, который входит в группу apache» — а для группы запись вы запретили. Ну и чего вы ожидали-то

Comment: Да,нет, это о ожидаемо, но настройки установлены стандартные для всех сайтов, поэтому и спрашиваю, кто-то же не как то делает,